# Create custom dropdown config values in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to create a custom dropdown having values of Enable/Disable in config file in magento 1.9 .How can I achieve this? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create it in config file? Do you want to edit module's configuration settings? If so, you need to do that in system.xml like shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="fme" translate="label" sortOrder="250">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="vendor_module" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>fme-separator</class>
            <label>Article</label>
            <tab>fme</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::resource_name</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

It'll make a Module Enable/Disable toggle in your module's configurations. Look under label "General" and in your config.xml you can set default value for this field like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <vendor_module>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
            </general>
   
        </vendor_module>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: As of now I edited in system.xml file m but how I add <source_model> in system.xml file and how I access while value is selected in dropdown in my files.

Comment: See my edit and tell me if it helps. :)

Comment: I answered the question you asked in this thread, if you've another question, you can ask separately so it would help others too. :)

Comment: Already , I have one custom module , in that I need a dropdown , as of now I edited the system.xml file in that module and add a dropdown , but for me how I pass the value to the dropdown from model by using <source_model></source_model>

Comment: Like in this site http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/22/magento-part9-series-systemxml-advanced/

Comment: You can make a new class in you Model like in my code above. Make a file in the directory : Vendor/Module/Model/Source/Yesno.php and enter your code there like given in the magento2 core at Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno. It's simple.

Comment: Thanks for the response and now its working fine.